# Delete all files xlsx in folder using C# ASPNET

Tags: c#, asp.net, delete-file

To create the Excel files (.XLSX) using `C# ASPNET` I have added the `Open XML` and `Closed XML` reference from nugget packages.

I can not understand why happen that when try delete files xlsx in folder.

> "the file is being used by another process."

The process is `w3wp.exe`

I need restart `IIS` on the server for delete all files in the folder.

Any suggestion?

```
public static void MTemptyxlxs()
{
    string AppLocation = "";
    AppLocation = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
    AppLocation = AppLocation.Replace("file:\\", "");

    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(AppLocation, "*.xlsx").Where(item => item.EndsWith(".xlsx")))
    {
        File.Delete(file);
    }
}

public static void  ExportDataSetToExcel(DataSet ds)
{
    string AppLocation = "";
    AppLocation = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
    AppLocation = AppLocation.Replace("file:\\", "");
    string date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    date = date.Replace("/", "_");
    string filepath = AppLocation + "\\ExcelFiles\\" + "RECEIPTS_COMPARISON_" + date + ".xlsx";

    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
           wb.Worksheets.Add(ds.Tables[i], ds.Tables[i].TableName);
        }
        wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
        wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        wb.SaveAs(filepath);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious; why are the files on disk in the first place? If you're creating them so you can send them, why not just stream them down the socket rather than streaming to disk then serving from disk?

Comment: @CaiusJard I need save for each day the files on disk

Comment: @Edward Not entirely sure that answers my question but.. If you wrap your Delete attempt in a try/catch is there any pattern to those that won't delete (like "massive ones that are only just created and probably still being downloaded by some poor sucker on slow  internet")

Comment: @mason *emailing them* - just curious if I missed something.. How did you know they're being emailed?

Comment: @mason thanks for reply but my code complete it's in the question. I don't have other code.

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles(AppLocation, "*.xlsx").Where(item => item.EndsWith(".xlsx")` is redundant; GetFiles with a pattern won't give you files that don't conform, unless you really are leveraging the case sensitivity of C#/insensitivity of win filesystems for something

Comment: This is the complete code? So you're generating XLSX files, then later removing them? Nothing happens with those files in the time between those operations? What is the purpose of generating them if you're only going to delete them?

Comment: My presumption for that is that theyre generated to disk and then the user picks them up somehow, such as the folder being literally mapped so a url of http://server.com/some/path/to.xlsx will have IIS serve the file, no involvement from C#. If that is the case, then probably having a C# handler for the serves, reading the file into memory and then pushing the memory bytes slowly down the socket would allow the files to delete...

Comment: ..but why bother - just try/catch the Delete, and if some file X didn't delete this time, then it will eventually... either the user won't be using it any more (downlaoding) and it'll delete next time, or some upgrade/restart will occur...

Comment: @mason the purpose is to generate them and store them on the folder shared with other users...